# My question is better suited for "serverfault" - can I move it?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've asked a question here on superuser (https://superuser.com/questions/511168/avahi-stops-publishing-after-a-few-minutes) that would probably be more suited to serverfault.com. Is there a way to move the question there? If not, is it OK to vote for close here and re-open it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved.

I would highly recommend making sure that the question is acceptable on that target site though. You can do that by checking their FAQ or join their chat room.

Comment: The question has already been moved, but thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Well [@Oliver](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5951/86550) has suggested you already to use the **Flag** option to move it. When you will flag the post it will notify the mods on the community and then they will decide to move it or not. If it better suits there, then they will otherwise not necessary.

Also you can consult with other users in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) of that site. Or you can ask it in [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) to other users and then if 5 people will vote for off topic and link to that site it will automatically moved there.